# Telegram Login widget doesn't render in React SPA app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, widget, telegram

I have a React frontend app (was bootstraped by create-react-app) and django at the backend. We have dev and production environments, they have different domains. Now I attempt to implement widget at dev env.

I want to login users via telegram login widget. I follow official core telegram [docs](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login). But button doesn't render at login page though there is the script into DOM tree

I try to move script to `<body>` in index.html outside div root where is mounting React, but behaviour was the same.
No errors in console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time we encountered the same problem

We tried to add the widget script directly to the JSX component, but nothing happens

Solved this problem by **creating a script element in the useEffect hook** (or can be in **componentDidMount**):

1. Created a ref where the Telegram iframe widget will be inserted:

```js
// Refs
const telegramWrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

...

return (
    <div ref={telegramWrapperRef}></div>
);
```

2. Defined the creation of the script element in useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22';
  scriptElement.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', 'paste-bot-name');
  scriptElement.setAttribute('data-size', 'large');
  scriptElement.setAttribute('data-auth-url', 'paste-redirect-url');
  scriptElement.async = true;

  telegramWrapperRef.current.appendChild(scriptElement);
}, []);
```

3. After that everything will work

I should note that on localhost it will also be noticeable, because the error "Bot domain invalid" will be displayed at the place of widget insertion (inside telegramWrapperRef)

To make it work properly, you need to deploy it with HTTPS.

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate you! Fortunately, I've already figured out the same decision on my own) but without ref